# How can I install wkhtmltopdf (unpatched qt) in docker file?

Tags: python, qt, docker, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

I have installed wkhtmltopdf(patched qt)0.12.4 which gives error using with pdfkit. I want to install unpatched qt version as does't give me error in my localsetup

my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl build-essential libssl-dev libxrender-dev git-core libx11-dev libxext-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev fontconfig libfontconfig1 libxrender1
RUN curl -L#o wk.tar.xz https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz \
&& tar xf wk.tar.xz \
&& cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin \
&& cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin \
&& rm wk.tar.xz \
&& rm -r wkhtmltox
WORKDIR /app/
COPY . /app
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 5000
```

MY docker compose File:

```
version: "3.7"

volumes:
   db_data:

services:
   db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: mycamdata
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
       - "3306:3306"

   adminer:
      image: adminer
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8080:8080

   app:
      build: .
      command: python run.py --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
      volumes:
         - .:/app
      ports:
         - 5000:5000
      depends_on:
         - db
```

While trying to create pdf I am getting this error:
i think this error is because of wkhtmltopdf(patched qt) version is not compitable with pdfkit. i want to install unpatched qt version

OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
[======================>                                     ] 38%
[===========================>                                ] 45%
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback

Comment: That Dockerfile doesn't have a `CMD`; how do you run it?  It seems like you're missing a couple of runtime C shared libraries too, what have you tried to install those?

Comment: I am using docker compose file , to run docker file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding the next lines to my Debian Buster image based dockerfile (wkhtmlto* version 0.12.6-1, June 2021)

```sh
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    # packages required by wkhtmlto*:
    xfonts-base \
    xfonts-75dpi \
    pdftk # -> only if needed... \
    # ...other custom packages...

RUN curl -L#o wkhtmltopdf.deb https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltopdf.deb; apt-get install -y -f

# Remember to clean your package manager cache to reduce your custom image size...
RUN apt-get clean all \
    && rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

You can find other builds of the same package here:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/0.12.6-1